# Unable to connect ESP8266 to Server

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have an ESP8266 module. I want to toggle GPIO 2 from a web page. I use 000webhost which has HTTPS protocol so I wrote related code.

**This is my Arduino Code:**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>





const char* ssid ="***";
const char* password ="*****";
const char* serverName = "https://ppcesp8266.000webhostapp.com/esp-outputs-action.php?action=outputs_state&board=1";

// Update interval time set to 5 seconds
const long interval = 5000;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

String outputsState;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
     // Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED ){ 
      outputsState = httpGETRequest(serverName);
      Serial.println(outputsState);
      JSONVar myObject = JSON.parse(outputsState);
  
      // JSON.typeof(jsonVar) can be used to get the type of the var
      if (JSON.typeof(myObject) == "undefined") {
        Serial.println("Parsing input failed!");
        return;
      }
    
      Serial.print("JSON object = ");
      Serial.println(myObject);
    
      // myObject.keys() can be used to get an array of all the keys in the object
      JSONVar keys = myObject.keys();
    
      for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
        JSONVar value = myObject[keys[i]];
        Serial.print("GPIO: ");
        Serial.print(keys[i]);
        Serial.print(" - SET to: ");
        Serial.println(value);
        pinMode(atoi(keys[i]), OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(atoi(keys[i]), atoi(value));
      }
      // save the last HTTP GET Request
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
  }
}


// Function 
String httpGETRequest(const char* serverName) {
  std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);

  // Ignore SSL certificate validation
  client->setInsecure();

  HTTPClient https;
    
  // Your IP address with path or Domain name with URL path 
  https.begin(*client, serverName);
  
  // Send HTTP POST request
  int httpResponseCode = https.GET();
  
  String payload = "{}"; 
  
  if (httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.println("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    payload = https.getString();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  https.end();

  return payload;
}
```

I don't receive any response with this code. It just shows me something ambiguous. How can I fix it?
If you think it would help, I can send my PHP codes too.

Comment: it should be an URL, including the protocol, not just a server name with path

Comment: It would make no difference. When I try with another server with https protocol, I get no response.

Comment: I've edited my post. I tried to use 000webhost server and edited my code according to HTTPS protocol but still haven't receive response. Would you please check again? @Juraj